# Disable UITableView Section with UISwitch

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a static UITableView with a grouped layout. In the first section there is just a UISwitch with which I want to disable/enable the second section. Does anyone know how to do that? If the switch is off then I want the second section to be disabled.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by “disabled.”

Possibly the UISwitch sets some state, which you read in -tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:. If the switch is on, return nil to avoid selecting rows in the second section.

If you also need to redraw disabled cells, it might be easiest to reload the table, and set them up the way you want them to look, depending on the state of the switch.